# Deleting random rows from a table without knowing anything about the table ids

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having a problem in mysql. I want to delete 20 rows from a table containing 100+ records.

I do not know the id's of the rows, any special identification of the rows to be deleted.
I want to just delete the any random rows from  my table.

Please help me... i am new to this condition.

Comment: Be sure to click the check mark next to your favorite answer or else nobody is going to want to help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do:

```
DELETE FROM tbl
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20
```

See [MySQL `DELETE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: Please note that ORDER BY RAND() might be very slow on big tables.